# Camellia (Camellia-Little-Leanne) loosing leaves after fertilising it

Tags: trees, camellia

my camellia tree looks likr it is dying after feeding it with a teaspoon of slow-release fertilizer. (Hortico plant fertiliser for flowers, fruits and veggies)
The leaves have started wilting and shedding without any new growth.

What should I do to revive this tree? Can someone please help?

Here’s a picture of the tree.

[image: Tree]

Comment: Its unlikely to be the fertiliser. Its more likely to be lack of water. Please post a closeup of a leaf just starting to wilt.

Comment: @RohitGupta I was going to put that exact comment!

Answer (score 1):

Camelia don't like full sun, but full to part shade. Yours is burning in the sun and is crying to be moved.

If moving it, roots are invariably lost. To compensate for fewer roots, prune heavily and improve the shape at the same time:

[image: Pruning sketch]

Also, camelia loves acid like azalea, blueberry, and roses. Only fertilize with "acid" or rose fertilizers, unless your soil is already acidic. If you transplant, you can use a root stimulator - even without an acid blend - to apologize for the shock of the move.

Comment: Thanks @Yosef. I’ll try that.